# Permissions to edit files on Montery in /System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app

Tags: keyboard, permission

I’m on a macOS Montery and I’m trying to add Romanian characters to the press and hold picker.

I found the file in which to add these characters:
/System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/PlugIns/PAH_Extension.appex/Contents/Resources/Keyboard-en.plist

I modified the file but I cannot replace the original one (nor edit it) because I keep running into permission issues.

- I switched off the System integrity Protection (csrutil status says it’s disabled)
- I gave Visual Studio Code AND Terminal Full Disk access but I still can’t edit nor replace.
- I tried to add myself as a user who can WRITE  to this particular file and several folders and packages in the hierarchy (including root) but it won’t let me.

I AM a admin user…

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You cannot modify the system volume. It is signed & sealed. [Not posting as an answer in case anyone knows how do implement this edit at user-level rather than system.]

Comment: Yes, you need to find a way to add the functionality, rather than replace the system files.

Comment: I wonder if something like [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) can modify press & hold? Might be worth investigating.

Comment: @Tetsujin ukelele can’t edit press and hold.  But if by chance some apple keyboard already has what you want on its accent menu, a ukelele layout can duplicate that